# use vs include as an import statement in PHP

Tags: php

I have 2 simple files:

file1.php

```
<?php
namespace NM\data;
class MyClass
{
    static function myStaticFunction(){
        echo __NAMESPACE__." heheh";
    }
}
function myfunction()
{
    echo __FUNCTION__." some data";
}
const MYCONST = 1;
```

and file2.php:

```
<?php
// include 'file1.php';
use NM\data as NM;
class MyClass
{
}
function myfunction()
{
    echo __NAMESPACE__." heheh";
}
const MYCONST = 2;
echo NM\myfunction();
```

The docs say that you can use `use` as an importing command for namespaces. http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

I had little success with importing namespaces with just `use`. For some other namespace to be used, I had to use `include`. But if I use `include`, than `use` is performs just an alias.

Is is possible to import a namespace just with the `use` keyword?

Comment: `use` and `include` are very different creatures; `include` includes a file, `use` associates a namespace, `use` does not include any files, importing !== including... there is no include vs use

Comment: Please look at http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php#example-258 . The example uses `use My\Full\Classname as Another;` but includes nothing. How is that then not an error? It must have imported a namespace from somewhere.

Comment: Stop confusing importing and including..... they are ___not___ the same thing at all.... `use` does __not__ include any files automagically, it simply provides an aliasing for classes.... either use `include` in addition to `use`, or use an autoloader to do the including

Comment: `use` only works for ***namespaces***, as you quote yourself. Namespaces literally only pertain to the naming of things. It's entirely unconcerned with loading the code from a file.

Comment: Perhaps I should rephrase my confusion. php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php#example-‌​258 uses `use My\Full\Classname as Another;` Where did namespace ` My\Full\Classname` come from? Is id declared in another file(which I do not need to include)?

Comment: I would think those kinds of details are omitted from the example in the manual for brevity.

Comment: Ok, so there should be an include statement at the of that example. thanks.

Comment: In practice you'd hopefully have set up autoloading, so no, there would be no explicit `include` statement, and including the details of an autoloader in the manual would obviously distract from the core message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But if I use `include`, than `use` is performs just an alias.

Yup, that's all `use` does. `use` just aliases namespaces. No more, no less. It is orthogonal to actually loading any piece of code from a file.

Comment: (Re now deleted comment:) Yes. The point of using a long name for your class/function is to disambiguate it and avoid naming clashes. The point of using PHP's namespace feature for long names is that you can alias them to short names, so you don't have to type out the entire long name every time you refer to the class/function. So aliasing is a rather important feature of namespaces. It still doesn't say that it'll locate the code itself for you.

Comment: aa, so `The ability to refer to an external fully qualified name with an alias == importing`. sorry about comment

Comment: @sanjihan You got it.

Comment: Damn that is a confusing way of saying things :D Thanks for taking your time.

Comment: So is there a way to load that piece of code perpendicularly? or in fact any other angle than orthogonal?

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is a way to do so. Read about autoload functions in PHP, I would suggest to look on [PSR-4 Autoloading](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/)

Before PHP 5.3 there was no namespace-s so files ware loaded by include function. On that time we had PSR-0 which loaded files by it's name but this was leading to long class names like "Mage_Admin_Model_Block". (this was resolved to file located in directory "Mage/Admin/Model/Block.php"

With namespaces introduced in php 5.3+ new autoloading standard was introduced, it is using namespaces to resolve path to file that contains definition of class that we want to use.

For example this 
`use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller`

is resolved to: 'Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller.php`

So PHP does not know where class file is located but with use of autoloader it can resolve where that file is present and load it if needed. You can write you're own code to do so but i would strongly suggest to stick to PSR-4 standard (PSR-0 is outdated now)

Comment: To be clear: autoloading has long existed before 5.3 or namespaces; PSR-4 just specifies rules to make cross-compatible autoloaders, specifically involving namespaces.

Comment: @deceze Yes true. Before PSR-4 we had "spl_autoload_register" and previous specification named PSR-0 so the concept existed long before php 5.3