# Object Oriented PHP, Class cannot be found

Tags: php, oop

I have a small task to create a Object Oriented PHP backend application which is to be used by an angular 7 frontend. This is a very small project with only few classes and my php project folder structure looks like,

```
 wamp/www/MyProject
  - MyObject.php
  - MyParser.php
  - index.php
```

MyParser class looks like,

```
<?php
namespace app\parse;

class MyParser
{
    public static function parse_object(){
        echo "in parse_object";
        // --- parse logic---
   }
}
```

And my index.php file looks like,

```
<?php

//---- some request processing here ---
use app\parse\MParser;
MyParser::parse_object();
?>
```

When I try to access index.php from the browser with http://localhost/MyProject/index.php
I get,

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'app\parse\MyParser' not found in C:\wamp\www\MyProject\index.php on line 9
( ! ) Error: Class 'app\parse\MyParser' not found in C:\wamp\www\MyProject\index.php on line 9
```

It would be highly appreciated if you can find out what I am missing here.

Comment: Are you using some kind of autoloader in your project? If not, you need to include the file containing the MyParser class explicitly, because `use` does not do that for you. Have a look at these questions:
[How does the keyword use work in php and can I import classes with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965454/how-does-the-keyword-use-work-in-php-and-can-i-import-classes-with-it) and [Use vs include as an import statement in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48263687/use-vs-include-as-an-import-statement-in-php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to be able to use `MyParser` static method, you need to explicitly require `MyParser.php`:

```
<?php

//---- some request processing here ---
use app\parse\MyParser;
require("MyParser.php");
MyParser::parse_object();
?>
```

If you want to be able to use it without the require, you have to use an [autoloader](https://vegibit.com/autoloading-for-code-organization/).